# postgres remove specific element from jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I am using postgres 10
I have a JsonArray in a jsonb column named boards.
I have a GIN index on the jsonb column.
The column values look like this:

```
[{"id": "7beacefa-9ac8-4fc6-9ee6-8ff6ab1a097f"}, 
 {"id": "1bc91c1c-b023-4338-bc68-026d86b0a140"}]
```

I want to delete in all the rows in the column the element

`{"id": "7beacefa-9ac8-4fc6-9ee6-8ff6ab1a097f"}` if such exists(update the column).

I saw that it is possible to delete an element by position with operator `#-` (e.g. `#-'{1}'`) and I know you can get the position of an element using "with ordinality" but i cant manage to combine the two things.

How can i update the jsonarray?

Comment: select boards - (position-1)::int from user_boards, jsonb_array_elements(boards) with ordinality arr(elem, position) WHERE elem->>'id' = '7beacefa-9ac8-4fc6-9ee6-8ff6ab1a097f';

return me the desired output but how do I update the rows now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using an update statement containing a query selecting all the sub-elements except `{"id": "7beacefa-9ac8-4fc6-9ee6-8ff6ab1a097f"}` by using an inequality, and then applying `jsonb_agg()` function to aggregate those sub-elements :

```
UPDATE user_boards
   SET boards = (SELECT jsonb_agg(j.elm)
                   FROM user_boards u
                  CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(boards) j(elm)
                  WHERE j.elm->>'id' != '7beacefa-9ac8-4fc6-9ee6-8ff6ab1a097f'
                    AND u.ID = user_boards.ID
                  GROUP BY ID)
```

where ID is an assumed identity(unique) column of the table.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=32ca4928175dce4aafba00963d258729)</kbd>